# what is the most efficient way to get the cyclic sum of an integer?

Tags: python, string, list, algorithm

if the input is 98352 then

`(9+8+3+5+2)+(8+3+5+2)+(3+5+2)+(5+2)+(2)=27+18+10+7+2=64`

thus output should be 64

my approach:

convert it to string ,find sum, then call recursively after removing the first digit.and repeat until the length of string is 0.I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: The first digit appears once, the second twice, and so on. No need for recursion.

Comment: `sum(i*int(digit) for i, digit in enumerate(num, start=1))`

Comment: @pyOliv, it assumes `num` is string; if you want it to be `int`, replace it as `str(num)`

Comment: You are right, I've deleted my comment as it was not relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to accumulate the sums in reverse:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> inp = 98352
>>> sum(accumulate(map(int, reversed(str(inp)))))
64
```